# How to install Bug Tracker .Net tool software in my System?

Tags: testing, bug-tracking

I have installed ASP .NET 2.0 MVC3, SQL server express 2005 and SQL server Management studio express 2005 and IIS 7 in my system. If I am opening the install_btnet file, and providing the SQL server details also it is not getting connect. It is giving error as Service unavailable. Any one suggest me how to install Bug tracker .NET tool in my system with examples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to check it that your SQL 2005 express instance is running and allowing remote connections. Open the Administrative Tools >> Services and look for the service called "MSSQLSERVER$SQLEXPRESS" and ensure it is started.

Next, open the SqlServer Configuration Utility (on the server or PC where SQL 2005 Express is Installed) Look for the Client Configuration Option and Select "Client Protocols".

Set TCP/IP to "Enabled" and you should now be able to connect to your SQL server.

Note that even if your BugTracker.NET install is on the same machine, it may still be using the network to connect to your SQL Instance.

Hope this helps, 
Dave

Comment: Hello Dave, thanks for your response, I went through your solution, In my system MSSQ Server express is started only, after that I could not find the client configuration option for client protocols. I am using windows 7, Where to find out that option please reply me, and I am inviting you on testers talk chat room. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Suseela, you can find the configuration options under Start > All Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager... in the config manager, select "SQL Native Client Configuration >> Client Protocols". HTH, Dave

Comment: @DaveLomg, I have tried the Gemini automatic installation, in that also it is not getting connect to the server, I have checked the client configurations options (TCP/IP) is enabled only, but still it not get connect to the server. I thought the problem with my sqlerver.